# Не отрабатывает @ControllerAdvice в юнит тестах вместе со Spring Boot 2 и JUnit 5

Tags: java, spring-mvc, юнит-тесты, spring-boot, junit

Использую Spring 5 вместе со Spring Boot 2. Для тестов использую junit 5. Хочу протестировать отлов ошибок в контроллере (для этого у меня есть специальный класс), но почему отлова ошибок не происходит.
Мой класс для тестирования контроллера:

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = ExportToMsExcelController.class, secure = false)
class ExportToMsExcelControllerTests {

    private static final String EXPORT_RESOURCE_1_URL = "/resource1/list/ms-excel"; // URL для rest-запроса по выгрузки в эксель
    private static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @MockBean
    private CreateXLSXDocumentService createXLSXDocumentService;

    /**
     * Тест выгрузки в файл в формате MS Excel,
     * входные данные: нет (search-строка не указана),
     * выходные данные: ошибка 500, непустой текст ошибки,
     * особенности: внутренний сервис вернул null
     *
     * @throws Exception любые исключительные ситуации
     */
    @Test
    void exportTable_noSearchStringAndInternalServiceReturnsNull_HttpCode500AndErrorMessageReturned() throws Exception {

        given(createXLSXDocumentService.createXLSXDocument(anyMap()))
                .willReturn(null);


        final MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(
                get(EXPORT_RESOURCE_1_URL)
                        .accept(CONTENT_TYPE)
        )
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isInternalServerError())
                .andReturn();

        final String errorMessage = mvcResult.getResponse().getErrorMessage();
        assertNotNull(errorMessage, "errorMessage is null");
        assertTrue(errorMessage.length() > 0, "errorMessage.length() <= 0");

    }
```

Класс для отлова ошибок:

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    private final static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(RestExceptionHandler.class);



//реализации методов абстрактного класса

    @ExceptionHandler({ NullPointerException.class })
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleNullPointerException(NullPointerException ex, WebRequest request) {
        logger.error(ex.getLocalizedMessage(), ex);
        return buildResponseEntity(new ApiError(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, ex.getMessage(), ex, null, new ArrayList<> (Arrays.asList(ex.getStackTrace()))));
    }
    @ExceptionHandler({ IllegalArgumentException.class })
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleIllegalArgumentException(IllegalArgumentException ex, WebRequest request) {
        logger.error(ex.getLocalizedMessage(), ex);
        return buildResponseEntity( new ApiError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, ex.getMessage(), ex, null, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(ex.getStackTrace()))) );
    }

    @ExceptionHandler({ RuntimeException.class })
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleRuntimeException(RuntimeException ex, WebRequest request) {
        logger.error(ex.getLocalizedMessage(), ex);
        return buildResponseEntity(new ApiError(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, ex.getMessage(), ex, null, new ArrayList<> (Arrays.asList(ex.getStackTrace()))));
    }

    @ExceptionHandler({ javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException.class })
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleConstraintViolationException(javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException ex, WebRequest request) {
        logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        String message = ex.getMessage();
        return buildResponseEntity(new ApiError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, message, ex, null, new ArrayList<> (Arrays.asList(ex.getStackTrace()))));
    }

    private ResponseEntity<Object> buildResponseEntity(ApiError apiError) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(apiError, apiError.getStatus());
    }
}
```

Причём при реальной работе программы отлов ошибок, вылетающих из контроллера, работает. А вот в тестах - нет.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить контекст в класс `ExportToMsExcelControllerTests`.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUintClassruner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={AppContext.class})
```

или указать пакет где находится ваш контекст

Comment: `@RunWith(SpringJUintClassruner.class)` не нужен, он уже есть в `@WebMvcTest`. А вот по поводу контекста надо смотреть. Использую пустой, чтобы всё работало, но нужно тогда как-то к нему добавить `ControllerAdvice`

Comment: Наверное на тему RUnWIth вы правы. Я хотел сказать, попробуйте поднять контекст, чтоб ваш ControlerAdvice создался

Comment: Ну вот тогда надо разобраться, как ему указывать путь к классу, а не пакету. Если это можно. Но пока, к сожалению, сейчас нет времени этим заниматься. Может как-нибудь займусь на досуге